# RestHighLevelClient to index the documents to a remote host?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, resthighlevelclient

I am trying to index to a remote elastic host but RestHighLevelClient by default is picking up the "localhost:9200" . is there any where i can configure the RestHighLevelClient to use a remote host instead of localhost?
I have researched enough on the internet but i could no find anything that could direct me regarding the remote host. I see "localhost" everywhere.

new RestHighLevelClient(
RestClient.builder(
new HttpHost("http://example.com")));

Any help would be appreciated.

Elastic Version : 6.2.3

Comment: did you get a chance to look into my answer?

Comment: Hi @Amit.. yeah it dint work for me.

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply replace `http://example.com` with your Elasticsearch hostname, for example if Elasticsearch cluster is running on ip 10.10.10.10 and on port 9200, you can give

```
new RestHighLevelClient( RestClient.builder( new HttpHost("http://10.10.10.10:9200")));
```

Above value is just a show the example, you need to replace it with your IP which needs to be accessible from the host where you code is running.